# Software able to link keywords to files

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm looking for a Windows software that would allow me to link keywords with files so that when I would press a key combination and enter that keyword, the file would be opened.

One keyword leads to one file but multiple keywords could lead to the same file. (Support for folders is optional.)

For example, if I link in the tool the keyword "ff" to the file Firefox.exe.
Let's say when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> I trigger the tool so now if I type "ff" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Firefox will open.

I know there is a Windows software for that but I'm unable to find it again.

Does anyone know the name of this software or any equivalent one?

Comment: So a particular keyword can only be used 1 time? And a particular file could have many associated keywords? // Only for files or also for folders?

Comment: Yes, one keyword leads to one file but multiple keywords could lead to the same file. I only thought about opening files but if it does open folders it could be usefull too.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I will try everything and keep you posted about my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Executor](http://executor.dk/). It is a launcher application for Windows that also supports keywords for different tasks. You can use it to link folders as well.

Another alternative is [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/about.php). It doesn't support custom keywords, but it can figure out what you mean: typing "ff" will suggest "FireFox"

Comment: After testing all the solutions, I chose Executor, it does exactly what I wanted and much more as it supports keywords but also indexed application and that is really handy.

Answer (score 1):

You use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Free, open-source, Windows) with [hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm), e.g.:

```
:*:ff::
Run firefox.exe, C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox, max
return
```

will open Firefox when you type `ff`.

In the hotstring, `*` (asterisk) indicates that an ending character (e.g. space, period, or enter) is not required to trigger the hotstring.

Comment: So if you write words like "fluffy" in some document, you have to get rid of the FF window in front of it to continue writing? o_O *LOL* Define a few more and have ff `<Alt-F4>`un :D

Comment: @Izzy Up to the OP to choose the best combination, hotstrings allow you to define pretty much anything, e.g. requiring to press enter after ff :)

Comment: Thought so. Sorry for the joke, but your example somehow provoked it ;)

Comment: @Izzy Yeah I quickly removed the shortcut from my AHK script :)

Comment: I finally chose to use Executor as it is easier to use and more complete but your proposition was interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with bookmarks.

A quick key sequence (as short as one key, if you like) prompts you for the bookmark name, which can be anything you like.

If you use Emacs library [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) then you can tag a bookmark with any number of arbitrary tags (any number of any characters). You can jump to bookmarks according to a set of tags they have, and so on.